# request.getRequestDispatcher and response.sendRedirect don't work

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets, dispatcher

Yes, I know that this is for sure duplicate question.
But... I have read all of answers for earlier asked questions, tried to fix everything... and my code still doesn't work.

In index.jsp:

`<form action="/Login"method="post">`

and

`<input type="submit" value="LogIn">`

In post method of servlet "/Login":

```
if (result == 1) {
RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
view.forward(request, response);
} else {
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
return;
}
```

I was trying with:

```
"http://localhost:8080/home.jsp",
"/home.jsp",
"home.jsp"
```

`response.sendRedirect`

trying to do with and without "return;".

And nothing.

This what I saw is only blank page and:
`If doPost()`
method: url is 
`"http://localhost:8080/Login"`.
`If doGet()`
 method: url is the same as abovementioned plus parameters input into a form.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user to another page with a brand new request then using `sendRedirect` function, but you must send redirect to the `servlet`, `servlet` will process and return to you a page. You can not `sendRedirect` directly to the `jsp` page (you send redirect to a jsp page, it's like you right click on jsp page and run it on server). Please refer to [this post](https://www.javatpoint.com/sendRedirect()-method) to see the use of `sendRedirect` method.